# How to suppress all GCC warning but errors

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I am looking for a GCC compiler option which can suppress all warning messages, but continue to report errors.

I tried the "[-w](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-w)" option with GCC 6.3, but it stops reporting all warnings *and* all errors.

Is there any such GCC option?

Comment: People might be more motivated to look for an answer if you gave a sensible reason for that wish.

Comment: `-Werror` is an option that makes GCC only produce errors, not warnings. I recommend always using it together with `-Wall`, and not `-w`. *I tried the "-w" option with GCC 6.3 but it stops reporting all warning and all errors.* Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the "-w" option with GCC 6.3, but it stops reporting all warnings and all errors.

There is *no way* this is true.

When GCC encounters an error, it can't proceed to compile your source, so it *must* report something.

To suppress all warnings (but not errors) use the `-w` flag.